# Spring boot not compiling due to QClass missing

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, querydsl

Hi im new to spring boot, ive been trying to integrate querDSL into my project but every time I package it it gives me errors. For example it would say my QClasses would not exist even though they have been properly imported through maven. Ive tried different versions of queryDSL but have come to no solution. I think its an issue with my pom file though I'm not sure as I had followed the tutorial made by [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb). Any advice would help, thank you.

**My exact error**

```
Error:(11, 8) java: cannot access com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier
  class file for com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier not found
This is in the Repo class below
```

**My Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>rc</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot-mongodb-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>springboot-mongodb-demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot with Mongo Db</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <querydsl.version>4.1.3</querydsl.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.6</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>
                            org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor
                        </processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**My Repo Layer code**

```
    package rc.springbootmongodbdemo;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.*;

@Repository
public interface HotelRepository extends MongoRepository<Hotel, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Hotel> {
    Hotel findByID(String id);
    List<Hotel> findByPricePerNightLessThan(int maxPrice);

    @Query(value = "{address.city:?0}")
    List<Hotel> findByCity(String city);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
I had a repository class that was extending MongoRepository. I was passing in the following

```
public interface HotelRepository extends MongoRepository<Hotel, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Hotel>{
```

after removing:
QuerydslPredicateExecutor

My error went away and my program began running again as it should.
I feel like the querydslpredicateexecutor is maybe an older code format and it wasn't compiling into my new version. Just a theory.

Answer (score 0):

check this question answered before
[Spring Boot+JPA+QueryDSL=OrderSpecifier not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739716/spring-bootjpaquerydsl-orderspecifier-not-found)

also go through this
https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-querydsl